# Mapbox(IOS): Retreive MGLVectorSource from style and updating it dynamically

Tags: mapbox

First of all, i just want to know how can i get the sources from mapview style by using "sourceLayerIdentifier" not by "sourceIdentifier".

And then how to update the features in it dynamically.

Below is my mapbox style source from console,

> "MGLSymbolStyleLayer: 0x171448040; identifier = myLayerIdentifier; sourceIdentifier = composite; sourceLayerIdentifier = mySourceLayer; predicate = $type == "Point"; visible = YES>"

And, this is my code to get the source from map,

```
if let mySource = mapView.style?.source(withIdentifier:"composite") as? MGLVectorSource{
       //my code
 }
```

In the above you can see, we need to use "sourceIdentifier" to get the source from mapView, but i need to use "sourceLayerIdentifier". Is there any way to get that.

Also, i need to update the features dynamically in the source layer.

Please help me on this, thank you.